# Wrong F1-Score for resulting Precision and Recall in sklearn.metrics

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I used the sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support() to output the evaluation of my classifier on a testset. I use average='macro'.
The function results in

precision = 0.153, recall = 0.144 and f1 = 0.122.

As we can see the f1-score is wrong for the resulting precision and recall (if I'm not mistaken). If we take the formula for f1 = 2 * p * r / (p + r), the f1-score should be about 0.148.

Does anyone know whether I'm wrong or why the function outputs that score?

Comment: Can you please provide some code that generates that output?

Comment: p, r, f1s_test, s = metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support(y_pred=YP, y_true=YT, average='macro', warn_for=tuple()), where YP and YT are lists of integers with the same length.
Edit: And the output is just a formatted string with '%.3f'